# Adjusting height immediately followed by ScrollTop is very jerky/choppy with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a page which contains a bunch of blocks (that would usually contain 'overflow: hidden' text that can be expanded by clicking on the box). But when I click on the box to adjust its height (to show all the text) I also want to bring that box into focus by using ScrollTop. It looks weird if you click on the box to expand its height if it remains out of view within the browser window.

I have a jQuery function that animates the height change and animates the ScrollTop repositioning nicely, however it often looks very choppy to me. It's not consistent. Sometimes it's pretty smooth, other times it'll adjust the box's height and then very abruptly scroll, which has a very unpleasant herky jerky effect. Adding to the odd behavior, is that I cannot scroll the window manually using my mouse for several seconds after the function completes. It's as if it's blocking manual mouse scroll.

I've created a little jsfiddle (sans text that I would usually place inside the right-hand boxes).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC8zW/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".right").click(function() {
      var currentHeight = $(this).height();
      $(this).animate({
      height: (currentHeight == 100 ? 200 : 100)
      }, 400, function() {
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: offset.top
      }, 1000);
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but the way you have it set up, the height will change, and **then** after it completes, it will move the scroll position, at a slower speed even.

Don't you want to do these at the same time and speed, instead of sequentially?

```
$(".right").click(function () {

    var currentHeight = $(this).height();
    $(this).animate({
        height: (currentHeight == 100 ? 200 : 100)
    }, 400);

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset.top
    }, 400);

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NpdDN/

Also, this will essentially "block" mouse scroll during the animation, because it is continually setting an absolute scroll position, overriding anything your mouse does.

Comment: Thanks. See my above response to razzak. Separating them does indeed help a lot. Is there no way to prevent mouse scrolling from being blocked? Why does the blocking persist even a few seconds after the SrollTop animation has completed?

Comment: I am not seeing any scroll blocking after the animation completes.  During the animation it is not really blocking per se.  Rather, any time you scroll, the animation comes along and moves the scroll position to the next animation "frame".

Comment: Odd. Guess razzak deleted his response. If I continually and immediately start spinning my mouse's scroll wheel right after clicking the box, it takes much longer than the 400 ms animation to respond.

Comment: The reason it blocks mouse scrolls despite having completed the animation, is that these blocks are near the bottom of the page, so it cannot truly bring them to the top of the window. So even though it completes the animation, it's still trying to (without effect) "move" the block up.